# Symfony2 - Using autoescape false in twig not working for {{include}}

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to use autoescape false in Twig for paragraph spacing in the index page, however it's not displaying the spaces regardless of the autoescape set to false.

Is there a way to use autoescape false on includes to show paragraph spacing?

**Doesn't work: (spacing is not displayed)**

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% autoescape false %}
        {{ include('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:_post.html.twig', { post: post }) }}
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endfor %}
```

**When I use it in the show page it works just fine:**

```
<div class="entry-content">
    {% autoescape false %}
        <p>{{ post.body|truncate(2000) }}</p>
    {% endautoescape %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `autoescape` tag has no scope over the included sub-templates.

> [You] can only mark a section of a template to be escaped or not.

You need to define  your autoescaping inside each included sub-templates.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html